# Altes Haus and alte Schachtel

Tags: german-to-english, slang

I was curious. I'm familiar with *altes Haus,* however my German cousin always calls me *alte Schachtel* (carton/box as opposed to House), because she thinks it's funny. Do they both mean the same thing, like 'pal' or is she calling me an old man, which I am ;)

We're very close, so it may be an insult in jest

Thanks

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schachtel

Comment: The German noun *»Schachtel«* is not neuter but feminine (wrong: *»**das** Schachtel«*. Correct: *»**die** Schachtel«*) and therefore it's not *»**altes** Schachtel«* (which is wrong) but *»**alte** Schachtel«*. And *»alte«* is not a noun but an adjective, and in German only nouns and words at the beginning of sentences are written with uppercase first letter. (There is nothing like *title case* in German). So it's neither *»Altes«* nor *»Alte«* but *»alte«.* I corrected this for you. ...

Comment: ... And because *»Schachtel«* is a feminine noun, it usually is used only for female persons, but when you are an "old man" this doesn't fit.

Answer (score 7):

"Altes Haus" und "Alte Schachtel" mean different things and have different connotations.

"Altes Haus" is a respectful way of saying "old pal" and has a positive connotation.

"Alte Schachtel" is usually only used for women and it normally means "strange" or "quirky" old woman... It's not purely negative, but has this touch of "crazy" in it...

If your cousin is a native German speaker then he for sure knows the difference.
So I'd guess it really is a little insult in jest, probably with a wink...

Comment: Disagree with the “strange” and “quirky”, sorry.

Comment: Might be a local thing... here in my surrounding it always has this connotation...

Comment: Being called "alte Schachtel" is most definitely an insult.

Answer (score 5):

I am a bit surprised that she would call you “alte Schachtel”, because that’s usually for women and that doesn’t fit your profile picture…

In a way, *altes Haus* and *alte Schachtel* are similar, but not exactly interchangeable.

*Altes Haus* ist used almost exclusively in direct communication between people who have a long-standing relationship. It falls roughly in the *buddy / mate / old boy* category and is typically used for males.

*Alte Schachtel* on the other hand is more frequently used when talking *about* a woman, and it’s derogatory, albeit on the milder side. It hints at someone clearly past their prime, but is not about physical age, rather about the traces left by life. It *can* be used as friendly ribbing when talking to another female, but needs careful judgement of the context.

Comment: I tend to disagree with your definition. While yes, it is used in this way, I feel it is used more mockingly. In my area (north western Germany) a “Schachtelbogen” ( arc build of cigarette or other packages) is made by her friends if a female has her 25th birthday and is not married. The male equivalent is the “Alte Socke” or old sock.

Answer (score 1):

*Altes Haus* is for sure a nice thing to be called. A good friend would say to you: "Na, altes Haus, lange nicht gesehen. Wie geht's dir?" I won't try to translate, because I think you have the right idea already about *altes Haus*. It's something that you are familiar with. Something that has it's own charm, awakens memories, feels like home. And it's something that two guys would call each other.

*Alte Schachtel* on the other hand is something that you would call only a female Person (what's kind of interesting imo). I have no idea, why that would only apply to a female person - but in fact it does. No native speaker that I know would use it for a male Person, me neither. I think, we'd need the opinion of a female person here to know, if two girls would call each other *alte Schachtel* in the same way as two guys would call each other *altes Haus*. I really don't know.

It doesn't mean the same as *altes Haus*. If it would - how could it be funny? While *altes Haus* clearly is something that you'd like to hear, *alte Schachtel* - if it come from a guy and goes to a girl (I guess) is not.

If I visit my mom and her partner and I say to him: "Na, du altes Haus!" - he would laugh and feel happy about that intimate, friendly greeting.

If I'd say to my mom then "Na, du alte Schachtel!", she wouldn't be overly happy. In this specific situation and knowing, that I don't want to hurt her, she would probably laugh to, knowing, it's a joke and show me somehow in her style, that she got the naughty joke. But it's still naughty. And I would never say that, because *altes Haus* is respectful, even lovely in this situation, *alte Schachtel* is not.

My mom would call herself an *alte Schachtel* when she is talking to me. So I'll really go for the same analysis as for *altes Haus* and think in pictures:

An *old box* is something that contains something that someone thought would be worth to preserve. So you can see it as a treasure chest. It might be just a simple box, but the content is precious to someone. Through the years you can see the signs of time passing by, ... A box is in the end just a box. A house is a house. And that might be the difference in perception if it comes to that two sayings.

So altogether: what's the funny part about calling you *alte Schachtel* - you really need to ask your cousin. Since she is female it might even be a kudo because you understand her in a way that only an *alte Schachtel* could. Or it just might be a joke as simple as mine, when I always say "Good Morning!", no matter what time of the day it is.

Whatever it is: for me it feels strongly like a lovely, inviting, intimate greeting.